# Posting a High Score in Facebook from Android App

Tags: android, facebook

I had just a Mastermind-like game app done in Eclipse Android. What I wanted now is for the user to have his/her score posted on his/her Facebook account. In an AlertDialog builder, when the user selects the "Post to my Facebook" button, it should be able to really do. Actual codes are highly appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to especially use just `Facebook` you should use the [FacebookSDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/) for Android.

But this may give you a lot of problems as far as I know, and instead I would recommend to make a `Share Intent` and let the users choose where to shere their score :

```
    Intent shareIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Your score and Some extra text");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "The title");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share..."));
```

This will let the user to choose from more applications installed on his phone such as Facebook, Twitter... etc.

Comment: okay.. i copy pasted the code.. then there is like a text bar in to top with the text "To". what is that suppose to contain?

Comment: this is because you are running the code on your emulator and the only app installed on the emulator that cand perform ACTION_SEND is the Messageing app. So what you actually see is the Messanging app. On a real device you would be able to pick your app first.

Comment: oh okay i will try that up.. so is there no other way to test this in the emulator?

Comment: by the way, i read about the need to register my app in facebook first before doing this.. do i still need to do that?